# Тестирование школьников базового уровня на знания C++

Tags: c++

Пожалуйста, подскажите, какой сайт можно использовать для подбора задач с решениями по языку `с++` для тестирования знаний школьников 6х классов?

Answer (score 2):

C++ как-то жестоко шестиклассниками преподавать. Если есть возможность, то можно попробовать Питон на уровне https://www.khanacademy.org или http://www.codecademy.com/

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю как насчет сайтов, но самые простейшие задания на понимание базовых конструкций можно найти в книге Абрамяна М.Э. - "1000 задач по программированию".